# How to join tables in MongoDb

Tags: mongoose

I have a meeting list. I have a list of participants. Wanting to know which participant is assigned to the meeting, I had the id of the participants. However, I need to add information whether the participant confirmed his presence and whether he came to the meeting. I don't know whether to add data to "friends".
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5yKk.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrxFY.png)

---

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piJiq.png)
I tried to do as in the picture. However, I don't know how to add default values later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add new data to subdocument you have to use mongodb $push method https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/push/

As I understand you want exactly to do that.